# Broadcom B43142 WiFi not working in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, broadcom

How can I get Wifi working in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

I have a Broadcom BCM43142 WLAN card.

The additional drivers tab does detect the network driver but the wifi still does not work and doesnot show up at the top right menu options

I know this question has been posted here about a million times.
I have tried everything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Comment: What "everything" did you try?

Comment: Read the webpage to which Pilot6 linked. In the Additional Drivers-tab you should have an option to install the recommended drivers. Try that first. You need an Ethernet cable from your computer to your internet source though, since Ubuntu will try to download the driver packages from the internet.

Comment: @Pilot6 I did try the additional driver tab. It shows my driver but an error saying my `dkms package has crashed` and the wifi doesnot work. 
i also have tried the link you provided did not work open to more suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the official `wl` driver after connecting to a wired network:

`$ sudo apt-get -y install bcmwl-kernel-source`